# entering custom type values in a config.json file

Tags: json, oauth, go

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/kjk/fofou) forum software written in Go that has a config file that requires the values you see in main.go below. I tried to use an empty string `""` for the oauth credentials to play around on my local machine but I got an error

```
json. json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type oauth.Credentials
```

So, even if I were to deploy it on a server, I thought I would have had to enter the credentials as a string, which would trigger the error there as well.

Assuming my api key and secret were like this

```
key= X482xYAFG1I2RKBYR
secret = 4929390593pqI4wNMljlj4N71oyOdlWCzyNKhv4BAd4QXLvW2LF
```

Taking into consideration the requirements from `main.go` below, how would you enter the credentials in a config.json file like this

```
{
    "TwitterOAuthCredentials":,
    "CookieAuthKeyHexStr":"2ded82bb63514dbd6a0af42a25df235c",
    "CookieEncrKeyHexStr":"4add93d1d6bb3489c9b3ab5448704068",
    "AnalyticsCode":"",
    "AwsAccess":"",
    "AwsSecret":"",
    "S3BackupBucket":"",
    "S3BackupDir": ""
}
```

config requirements from **main.go**

```
config = struct {
    TwitterOAuthCredentials *oauth.Credentials
    CookieAuthKeyHexStr     *string
    CookieEncrKeyHexStr     *string
    AnalyticsCode           *string
    AwsAccess               *string
    AwsSecret               *string
    S3BackupBucket          *string
    S3BackupDir             *string
}{
    &oauthClient.Credentials,
    nil, nil,
    nil,
    nil, nil,
    nil, nil,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to set it, leave it out entirely, and it will get set to the default value.

Otherwise, enter the json representation of an `oauth.Credentials`, which is just a `Token` and a `Secret` string:

```
type Credentials struct {
    Token  string // Also known as consumer key or access token.
    Secret string // Also known as consumer secret or access token secret.
}
```

In your config, the credentials would look like:

```
"TwitterOAuthCredentials": {
    "Token": "oauthtoken",
    "Secret": "oauthsecret"
},
```

Comment: Thanks can you show how it would look in the `config.json` file in my OP. how do I wrap the Token and String in the config.json file with that `type Credentials struct`, since they have to be wrapped (because it throws an error if they're strings as my OP says)

Comment: Added. You can always just run a struct through `json.Marshal` to see what comes out too.